# Why does this module.export function not work if I pass it directly but works if I wrap it in an anonymous function

Tags: node.js

I'm following a tutorial for setting up a Slack bot and trying to tidy up the code to make it more readable by moving some functions to other files.

The initial state before I tried to rearrange things looked like this:

```
app.event('app_home_opened', async ({event, client, context}) => {
  // things happen over 50 lines
})
await app.start()
```

---

I then tried to rearrange that to something like this:

**app.js**

```
const handleAppHomeOpened = require('./events/app_home_opened.js')
app.event('app_home_opened', handleAppHomeOpened)
await app.start()
```

**events/app_home_opened.js**

```
async function handleEvent({event, client, context}) {
  // things happen
}
module.exports = handleEvent
```

When I run app.js in this version, I get the error `TypeError: app.event(...) is not a function`.

---

If I update app.js as follows then it executes correctly:

```
const handleAppHomeOpened = require('./events/app_home_opened.js')
app.event('app_home_opened', async ({event, client, context})=>{
  handleAppHomeOpened({event, client, context})
})
await app.start()
```

Is there a way to adjust that second one so it works instead of that extra step of wrapping the function call in an anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I then tried to rearrange that to **something like this**

The code you posted doesn't reproduce the error you claimed it does, and I bet your actual code is different.  So I'll do some detective work and make a prediction.  Let's begin by breaking down your error:

```
> a = 1
1
> a()
Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
```

The error is that `a` is not a function.  Not quite the format of your error.  Here the number 1 is not a function.  So far so good.  But let's try to get closer to your error.

```
> app = {}
{}
> app.event = 1
1
> app.event()
Uncaught TypeError: app.event is not a function
```

A little closer, but notice we're missing the `(...)` part in the error.  Here `app.event` is not a function.  (it's a number).  Let's keep going.

```
> app.event = () => 1
[Function (anonymous)]
> app.event()()
Uncaught TypeError: app.event(...) is not a function
```

Aha!  This error has the right format.  It means that the value returned when the function `app.event` is called (e.g. with `app.event()`) was not a function.  And indeed we made it so that the return value of `app.event()` is just the number 1.

Let's make it return a function

```
> app.event = () => () => 1
[Function (anonymous)]
> app.event()()
1
```

Great!  it works.  So what did you likely do?  Well, you have `async` in there, and an unawaited async function returns a promise.  let's demonstrate

```
> app.event = async () => () => 1
[AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
> app.event()()
Uncaught TypeError: app.event(...) is not a function
```

This may be what you did -- somehow.  (The fix would be to await the promise that returned a function.)  I can't be sure because your code snippet is incomplete and not representative of the actual error.

#### But it could be one other much simpler thing;

I predict, because you are not using semicolons at the end of the line, that you may have accidentally called a function like this:

```js
app.event('app_home_opened', async ({event, client, context}) => {
  // things happen over 50 lines
})
(somethingInParenthesesHere)
```

The above is a famous ambiguity for automatic semicolon insertion in JavaScript.  It makes it look like `app.event()(somethingInParenthesesHere)`, like you're calling the result of `app.event()` as a function and passing `somethingInParenthesesHere` as an argument.

A common kind of "somethingInParenthesesHere" is an IIFE.  e.g.:

```js
app.event('app_home_opened', async ({event, client, context}) => {
  // things happen over 50 lines
})

(function (){ /* blah-blah-blah */ })();
```

Such a problem could be corrected by adding the semicolon in the right spot.

```js
app.event('app_home_opened', async ({event, client, context}) => {
  // things happen over 50 lines
});   // <-- semicolon is needed in this case.

(function (){ /* blah-blah-blah */ })();
```